# regular expressions, delimiting plus sign

Tags: regex, vb.net

```
Private Const SEPARATOR_REG_EXP1 As String = "SCD\+4\+[A-Z]\+"

Public Function TestReg() As Boolean
    Dim s1 As String = "SCD+4+ADJUSTMENT+"
    Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(s1, SEPARATOR_REG_EXP1)
    If match.Success Then
        Return True
    Else : Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Not sure why this does not match - haven't really used regular expressions much.

Comment: ok figured it out "SCD\+4\+[A-Z]{1,}\+"

Answer (score 1):

The regex pattern should be :

```
"SCD\+4\+[A-Z]+\+"
```

You have to add a `+` sign after `[A-Z],` because you want to match one **or multiple** of these `[A-Z]` characters.

Answer (score 0):

This does not match, because `[A-Z]`matches only a single character of the given character class. You can use the `+` quantifier to match multiple chars. The resulting RegEx would be

```
SCD\+4\+[A-Z]+\+
```